# Alterar PrimaryKey EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Como alterar uma primary key utilizando o EntityFramework?

Tenho uma tabela com PK simples e preciso alterar essa PK pelo EntityFramework.

Comment: Não é muito viável fazer isso pelo Entity Framework. Você tem um bom motivo para isso?

Comment: Eu sei que não é uma boa pratica, mas infelizmente preciso fazer isso

Answer (score 0):

> A solução abaixo talvez funcione, como não testei, eu peço que o faça,
>   caso não funcione, por favor comente logo abaixo para que eu possa
>   remover esta resposta.

Primeiro passo, você deverá alterar todas as suas FKs que referenciam a chave que deseja alterar.

Como o EF parte da premisa que a PK nunca será alterada, você não terá como fazer isto pelo Migrations, então se estiver utilizando o SQL Server, pode executar um script como este.:

```
alter table Detail 
  drop constraint FK_Master_Detail

alter table Detail 
  add constraint FK_Master_Detail 
      foreign key (MasterID) 
      references Cars(MasterID) 
      --on delete cascade 
      on update cascade
```

A segunda coisa a ser feita, é instalar o seguinte pacote.:

[**Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/)

Então execute o seguinte comando...

```
ctx.Entities
    .Where(x => x.EntityID == oldEntityID)
    .Update(x => new Entity() { EntityID = newEntityID });
```

Apenas para lhe lembrar, não lhe dou qual quer garantia que o código acima funcione. porem você tem mais uma opção, que seria utilizando Raw Sql, para tal eu te aconselho a utilizar o [**Dapper**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/).

```
await ctx.Database.Connection
    .QueryAsync("UPDATE Entities SET EntityID = @newEntityID WHERE EntityID = @oldEntityID", 
        new { newEntityID = newEntityID, oldEntityID = oldEntityID }
    );
```

por fim, apenas uma sugestão, não utilize chaves naturais, dê preferencia à uma chave substituta. s você pode vir a declarar as suas tabelas da seguinte forma.:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Entities (
    EntityID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    NaturalID int NOT NULL --IDENTITY (1, 1)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE dbo.Entities ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Entities PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (EntityID) 
    WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IXCU_Entities 
    ON dbo.Entities (NaturalID) 
    WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

E lembre-se, jamais exiba as suas chaves substitutas para o usuário final, ele não precisa e nem deve saber da existência delas.